# Windows 10 Network Share Performance

Tags: networking, windows-10

So I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a little while now for this small business I'm working with - having a bit of a weird issue since changing from Windows 7 to Windows 10. It looks like for some reason, their network share which is not password protected hangs when trying to create a new folder. Also getting this error when trying to delete a new folder or update a file.

Scenario: I will access the network share via another PC, create a new folder, name it, hit enter. Window will then fade out, I get (Not Responding) up the top, and it only resumes after what seems to be exactly two minutes, when the file finally is created.

Same issue happens when I try to remove it - I get "Calculating - 0 bytes", and it hangs for two minutes.

This is a bog standard install, from Microsoft's own USB - I have not installed any third party software bar Office 2016 and their fairly simplistic software they use to manage their company.

Permissions for 'Everyone' are set to Full Access for troubleshooting reasons - I can access the folder and execute files from the network share. I have tried to disable the Windows timeout (setting it to -1 via command prompt) to no avail.

Network equipment has been changed, ruling that out (as well as the cabling). They're accessing a .mdb over the network, and this particular issue causes intermittent freezing in the program they're using.

Would there be any settings I'm missing, or even a bug I'm not aware of? Happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: known issue for 1607: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b72c763e-d029-4e65-a2dc-885a5aabf643/problem-creatingrenaming-a-folder-on-a-network-share-with-win10-anniversary-update-error?forum=win10itpronetworking

Comment: Sweet - thanks! I ended up finding the update on the MS catalog and it fixed the issue. Cheers!

Comment: ok, I posted it an answer, so that you can accept it now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [long known](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b72c763e-d029-4e65-a2dc-885a5aabf643/problem-creatingrenaming-a-folder-on-a-network-share-with-win10-anniversary-update-error?forum=win10itpronetworking) issue [since Windows 10 v160](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3198614/EN-US)7.

The workaround is to exclude Windows Search for the mapped drive/file share on the server. Microsoft fixed it now with the [update KB3216755, that is available in release Preview Ring](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=3216755).

In March 2017 the fix was part [of the update rollup on patchday](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4013429). It was planned to be released in February 2017, but the patchday was skipped. So Install [KB4013429](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4013429/en-us) to fix it.

The creators Update (currently in Insider Fast/slow Ring) has the issue fixed for some time (> Build 1496x).